# SQL Server returns ?? in processmaker

Tags: sql-server, processmaker

In process maker, when I query from SQL Server I get `???` as a result.

I try change database collation to Arabic_CI_AI but does not work and I try to use utf8_encode and utf8_decode in process maker but this does not work, too.

I don't know what am I doing.

Comment: **Most likely** your datatype is `VARCHAR(n)` and that doesn't work for languages like Arabic, Hebrew, Cyrillic, Japanese, Chinese etc. - you need to use `NVARCHAR(n)` to get **Unicode** (2-byte-per-character) strings, and if you ever specify a **string literal** in your T-SQL code, you **must** prefix it with a `N'...'` to indicate a Unicode string literal.

Comment: my datatype is NVARCHAR 

and my SQL code is

select [DepartmentID], [Name] from [webCopy].[HumanResources].[Department]

Comment: Please post DDL,DML Of the tables involved .Having this info helps others to quickly repro your issue and asnwer better.Below is some sample which might help you understand.  

**--sample data**  
`create table t1
(
id int
)

insert into t1
values
(1),
(2),
(1)
`    
**my current query/what i have tried:**   
`select id,count(*) as cnt from
t1
group by id`  

**my current result:**  
`id cnt
1  2
2  1`

**my expected result:**
`id cnt
1  2
2  1
1  2`

Comment: my current query 

`use [webCopy]
go
select [DepartmentID], [Name] from [webCopy].[HumanResources].[Department] where [DepartmentID] in (

select [DepartmentID] from [webCopy].[HumanResources].[EmployeePosition] where [EmployeeID] = (select [UserManagementID] from [webCopy].[Security].[UserManagement] where [username] = '94073599')
);`

and my expected result is `7210268 | کارشناس IT فهامه`
but I get `7210268 | ?????`